# Share a Linux Host's Folder With a Windows Guest Without Networking

Tags: kvm-virtualization, network-share

I need to share a linux host's folder with a Windows guest, however this Windows machine will not be allowed to have internet support so no NIC will be added to the device. How do I share a folder with a Windows guest without internet?

Comment: Don't bother to tell me what was wrong with my post...just mark it down because you don't like it....

Comment: Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be for one of the reasons listed in the downvote arrow hover text.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Add a network interface, bind it to a host-only network on the KVM host and be done with it (you can also add firewall rules of course).

Comment: You'll have to excuse me if I hold out hope that the KVM devs are more competent than the Virtualbox devs.

Comment: Just because you think something should be available doesn't mean devs are incompetent when it's not.

Comment: Why wouldn't having no internet for a Windows machine be a valid use case? If they haven't added this functionality for Windows but left it available for Linux they are either incompetent or lazy (which is just as bad).

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about. As I said, you can have host-only networking without having actual internet access. Having shared access to a file system is a real hard problem and it would be complete, useless waste of time to implement this in a virt engine if you can just use the available methods.

Comment: Networking != Internet.